# Correctly put together string for RestMethod in a PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell

This Url Request works nicely

```
$URL =  'https://api.github.com/repos/powershell/powershell/issues'
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Method GET -Headers $headers
```

when I replace the $URL String for my own url/api PS complains

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Method GET -Headers $headers
 |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 | Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
```

Url string has been put together like that

```
$URL = 'https://example.com/api/${YEAR}/${PAGE}/en?token=${API_KEY}'
```

writing out the URL string to console and using it in a request or directly in a browser works.

How would I have to do it in a ps1 script ?

Comment: Assuming you want the variable expressions `${YEAR}`, `${PAGE}` and `${API_KEY}` expanded, use `"` (double-quotes) instead of `'` (single-quotes). See [the `about_Quoting_Rules` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules)

Comment: that did work. If you post it as an answer I would give extra kudos for the link